# Set Label text to non-transparent

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a grid with labels, each "Tile" has a transparent background color, however the text also appears to be transparent. Is there a way to remove the transparency from the label text?

**My code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.GridMenu"
             BackgroundImage="grid.jpg"
             Title="Main Menu"
             >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="Cards" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#1481BA"  Opacity="0.5" x:Name="CardTile"/>
        <Label Text="Transactions" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#ede890" Opacity="0.5" x:Name="TransactionTile"/>
        <Label Text="Promotions" TextColor="White" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#1481BA"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0.7" x:Name="PromoTile"/>
        <Label Text="Settings" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#ede890" Opacity="0.5" x:Name="SettingsTile" />
        <Label Text="My Profile" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#1481BA" Opacity="0.5" x:Name="ProfileTile"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

ScreenShot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You probably need to create one `Label` (or maybe `BoxView` or `Frame`) for the background color and then a `Label` with a transparent background but not the text, so the text will be shown clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your label in `StackLayout` look like this :

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#1481BA" Opacity="0.5" >
    <Label Text="Cards" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="CardTile"/>
</StackLayout>
```

You can also use `Frame` in place of `StackLayout`

Answer (score 0):

On the labels, set the BackgroundColor property to 0.5 alpha (128 = 0x80) and keep Opacity at 1.0.

```
  <Label ... BackgroundColor="#801481BA"  Opacity="1.0" />
```